# How to pass content bytes from ASP.NET WebAPI to Power Automate escaping corruption files

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, power-automate

I am writing my API, and I probably have some limited knowledge of working with files in C# ASP.NET stack. However, I have a custom POST-endpoint that should take a file's content of bytes in the local directory, and send them into Power Automate flow.

Here is a separate code chunk used in HTTP POST to send content to Power Automate flow that sends to SharePoint:

```
[NonAction]
public async Task<bool> UploadFilesToSP()
{
    //TODO -- the right content is not sent
    Client client = new Client(_urlPostSP_UploadFiles);
    string docPath = _fileManager.path + "\\Test1.docx";

    //attempt 1 -- use StringContent as a content
    //returns -- triggers the PA flow, but file is corrupted 
    var content = new StringContent(_fileManager.GetFileContentBytes(docPath));


    //attempt 2 -- use HttpContent byte instead of StringContent
    //result -- the flow fails, reason is no content actually sent             
    /*
    var content = new ByteArrayContent(_fileManager.GetFileContentBytes(docPath));
    var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    formData.Add(content);
    */

    var response = await client.PostAsync(content);
    return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

I made two attempts using `StringContent` and  `MultipartFormDataContent`. I am calling `GetFileContentBytes` method which is basically:

```
public string GetFileContentBytes(string filepath)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] fcontent = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(fcontent);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, it returns the `String64` type. While in the attempt #2, it returns `byte[]` (realization is the same, different returning type).

My guess, why the file may be corrupted, are

- `String64` and `StringContent` have limitations in size, so they needs a lot of RAM to keep all in memory
- Thus, it provides only a truncated string, not the whole content of bytes.

The current file is not big, however, how can I handle big files?

Is there a way to pass content more effectively, and don't lose a byte?

I know there is a SharePoint interface GET/POST, but I need a Power Automate flow because it is more powerful for my purposes.

My flow looks like the following:

1. [image: Power Automate flow blocks]
2. [image: Body is a content of bytes]
3. [image: My content bytes passed to the Power Automate. Does it look good?]

Overall my questions are:

1. How to provide big content of bytes to Power Automate through my HTTP Post interface?
2. Is my function "GetFileContentBytes" correct? Do I miss something?
3. Do I need to use *base64ToBinary* in the Power Automate function, because last time when built an app in PowerApp I used it, and it helped me to escape corrupted files?

Any piece of advice will be super helpful.